# Open full Image from gridview in new Activity

Tags: java, android, gridview

I tried to make general gridview and categorical gridview , from categorical gridview try to open clicked image in new activity .

THE PROBLEM IS WHEN click item in categorical gridview it doesn't open the new Activity

second gridview "categorical ":

```
     holder.tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        holder.tv.setText(Bresult[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(BimageId[position]);

        if (row == null) {
            row = new ImageView(Bcontext);
        }
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Bcontext, BActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                if (position==0){
                    intent.putExtra("imageID", position);
                    Bcontext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                Toast.makeText(Bcontext, "You Clicked " + Bresult[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        return row;
    }
}
```

And this the New Activity should image appear there :

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    BCustomAdapter imageAdapter = new BirthCustomAdapter(this);
    Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
    int index = bdl.getInt("imageID");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view);
    image.setImageResource(index);
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your Logcat?

Comment: @DhanukaLakshan No, it just doesn't work as i want .

Answer (score 0):

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Bcontext, BActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        if (position==0){
            intent.putExtra("imageID", position);
            Bcontext.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Your `startActivity()` is *inside* the `if` statement, so your activity will only be started if position == 0.

Perhaps you really meant this:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Bcontext, BActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        if (position==0){
            intent.putExtra("imageID", position);
        }
        Bcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Kris_larson Thank you but , position 0 is related to the image in gridview i want when clicked open the full image in new activity .